# How can I link from one location to another?

Tags: duplicate, document

I have a directory of files and accidentally got two versions of the same document under different names, how can I create a symbolic link from one to the other, so that there is only one file, yet keep the duplicate link working since some might be using it?  Ideally the link would be invisible, since it is only for backwards compatibility and not useful for browsing the files in the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint does not support symbolic links. An alternative solution would be to create a link from the incorrect location/folder of the files to the correct location/folder of the files.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the link?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to automatically redirect from the old/incorrect location to the new/correct location?

Comment: Yes, but not advertise the old location.

Comment: That's odd.  I thought symlinks operated at Window's file system level.  From SharePoint's perspective I would hope it wouldn't care whether the file is an original or a link.  Not supporting symlinks makes tools like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created a link:

1. In SharePoint select the folder you want the link to point, go to "Show actions" popup menu (i.e. the three dots icon shown when hovering over the folder) and select "Copy link" and copy the link.
2. Go to the folder where you want or need the link. From the "New" menu select "Link". In the popup window paste the copied link in the entry box below "Create link to" and press "Enter"
3. A file type "Link" will appear in the folder where you want or need the link.